# Can't open a database created on 2.0.0 M02

Tags: neo4j

I have tried opening this database, with allow_store_upgrade=true using 2.0.0 M06 as well as 2.0.0 GA freshly downloaded minutes ago.

My colleague had created a prototype DB using M02 on a Mac and now I want to set it up on my Windows machine but with no luck so far.  I understand from poking around that certain versions aren't necessarily convertible to other versions.  Is M02 -> M06+ one of those cases?  Is there an issue with Mac to Windows?

Comment: It would help if you offered more details to support "no luck so far." Can you please edit your question to add the errors you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

You should use 2.0.0 final as the new database.

I think mac to windows is no problem.

The problem is that there is no upgrade support between milestones.

How large is the database?

When it is not too large you can export it with the `dump` command in the neo4j-shell.

`bin/neo4j-shell -path old/graph.db -c dump > import.cql`

And import it in 2.0.0 with

`bin/neo4j-shell -file import.cql -path new/graph.db`

If it is larger then it makes more sense to perhaps recreate the database.

Or you can export database in a different format like CSV and then import it again.

Comment: Could probably do the dump/import incrementally if the db is large, no? Since you can dump the results of a query, it should be possible to match, return, dump, delete & import some subset of the graph, repeat until done. Haven't tried but seems like it should work.